How do I order signatures on a letter from my organization and 6 others?
I am writing a letter jointly from my employer and multiple interested organizations.
The letter will feature the names of all heads of organisations but it will be using my employer's letterhead and stationery. I do not wish to offend our collaborators by implying an order of importance.
My question is:
Is there an accepted standard for listing co-signatures/co-sponsors (format, order, etc.)? And does that apply to all names, our own director's included, even though the letter is mainly from us?

Why can't you simply use a blank template that does NOT have your "employer's letterhead and stationery" ? Why don't you use any text editor such as MS words, and type whatever you want to in that blank template ?

@Or4ng3h4t it's a fair point. However, it's not about not offending other people, it's about representation of organisations. So unless there is a Stack site for interorganisational politics, I think this one's a better fit :)

If there a significant number (I'd say 5 or more) can you just list them in alphabetical order?

Do these organizations share a region or culture?

I don't think anyone is going to get upset over their place in the order that you list their names on this letter. The easiest system to make it incredibly obvious however would be to just go alphabetical, by name or better yet by company. Sincerely, signed: Jim Smith, AA Inc; Dan Jones, Cx International; Mary Xi, HP and etc.  The letterhead shows that your company took point on drafting this letter, and your company being in its rightful place in the signature order shows that it is a co-sponsor equivalent to everyone else.

"I don't think anyone is going to get upset over their place in the order that you list their names on this letter." If Company Z has provided 50% of the funding for the project and Company A has provided 1%, Company Z could quite possibly get upset at being last in the list.

Strictly speaking, anyone can be upset about anything. All you can do is pick an option to limits that likelihood and I'd say this option is it.


Is there an accepted standard for listing co-signatures/co-sponsors (format, order, etc.)?

No.
I know that's a very brief answer, so to expand a bit: it's a mistake to think there is a global "accepted standard" for anything. Some fields will do things one way, some fields will do things another way. Some locations will do things one way, some locations will do things another way.

Well, fair enough, you did answer the question as it was asked. But I think all I can take from it is that I should not have included the word 'accepted' and just asked if there was a standard, any standard, to lean on.

There are 14 competing standards...

Ask?

Good morning,
I've finished the draft; please review and provide feedback. In particular, does your organisation have any preference in the ordering of cosponsors? The current listing is based on signatories' perceived body mass.
Regards,
brokkr

